# Can iPod touch / iPad apps written in safari run without internet access?

Tags: web-applications, ipod-touch

I know that for native apps, after I download them, I can run them without a network access.

I also know that for safari webapps, I can run them, and the server can store the data.

However, is there a way to write a webpage, save it to my iPhone, allow it to do i/o to the iPod touch itself, and also run it without web access?

[Think a todo list written as a webpage; but I want it with me and running even when I don't have network access.]

Thanks!

If not possible; please provide link. If possible, please tell me now.

Comment: ... when safari supports HTML5 "offline apps"

Comment: whoever that votd to close; how is this not programming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to check out the following article:

- [How to create offline webapps on the iPhone](http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/how-to-create-offline-webapps-on-the-iphone)

It explains how to create offline web applications for the iPhone, by using a cache manifest file, which contains references to all the resources that need to be saved for offline use, like JavaScript, CSS, images or HTML.